# Dask bag from multiple files into Dask dataframe with columns

Tags: dataframe, dask, bag

I am given a list of filenames `files` which contain comma-delimited data which has to be cleaned as well as further extended by columns containing information based on the filenames. Thus, I implemented a small `read_file` function, which handles both, the initial cleaning, as well as the computation of additional columns. Using `db.from_sequence(files).map(read_file)`, I am mapping the read function to all of the files, getting a list of dictionaries each.

However, rather than a list of dictionaries, I want my bag to contain each individual line of the input files as an entry. Subsequently, I want to map the keys of the dictionaries to column names in a dask dataframe.

```
from dask import bag as db

def read_file(filename):
    ret = []
    with open(filename, 'r') as fp:
        ... # reading line of file and storing result in dict
        ret.append({'a': val_a, 'b': val_b, 'c': val_c})

    return ret

from dask import bag as db
files = ['a.txt', 'b.txt', 'c.txt']
my_bag = db.from_sequence(files).map(read_file)
# a,b,c are the keys of the dictionaries returned by read_file
my_df = my_bag.to_dataframe(columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

Could someone let me know what I have to change to get this code running? Are there different approaches that would be more suitable?

Edit:
I have created three test files `a_20160101.txt`, `a_20160102.txt`, `a_20160103.txt`. All of them contain just a few lines with a single string each.

```
asdf
sadfsadf
sadf
fsadff
asdf
sadfasd
fa
sf
ads 
f
```

Previously I had a small error in `read_file`, but now, calling `my_bag.take(10)` after mapping to the reader works fine:

```
([{'b': datetime.datetime(2016, 2, 1, 0, 0), 'a': 'asdf', 'c': 'XY'}, {'b':    datetime.datetime(2016, 2, 1, 0, 0), 'a': 'sadfsadf', 'c': 'XY'}, {'b': datetime.datetime(2016, 2, 1, 0, 0), 'a': 'sadf', 'c': 'XY'}, {'b': datetime.datetime(2016, 2, 1, 0, 0), 'a': 'fsadff', 'c': 'XY'}, {'b': datetime.datetime(2016, 2, 1, 0, 0), 'a': 'asdf', 'c': 'XY'}, {'b': datetime.datetime(2016, 2, 1, 0, 0), 'a': 'sadfasd', 'c': 'XY'}, {'b': datetime.datetime(2016, 2, 1, 0, 0), 'a': 'fa', 'c': 'XY'}, {'b': datetime.datetime(2016, 2, 1, 0, 0), 'a': 'sf', 'c': 'XY'}, {'b': datetime.datetime(2016, 2, 1, 0, 0), 'a': 'ads', 'c': 'XY'}, {'b': datetime.datetime(2016, 2, 1, 0, 0), 'a': 'f', 'c': 'XY'}],)
```

However `my_df = my_bag.to_dataframe(columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])` and subsequently
`my_df.head(10)` still raises `dask.async.AssertionError: 3 columns passed, passed data had 10 columns`

Comment: What is wrong with having a bag of dictionaries and then passing to to_dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to call `flatten`

Your bag of filenames looks like this:

```
['a.txt', 
 'b.txt', 
 'c.txt']
```

After you call map your bag looks like this:

```
[[{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}, {'a': 10, 'b': 20, 'c': 30}],
 [{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}],
 [{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}, {'a': 10, 'b': 20, 'c': 30}]]
```

Each file was turned into a list of dicts.  Now your bag is kind of like a list-of-lists-of-dicts.

The `.to_dataframe` method wants you to have a list-of-dicts.  So lets concatenate our bag to be a single flattened collection of dicts

```
my_bag = db.from_sequence(files).map(read_file).flatten()

[{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}, {'a': 10, 'b': 20, 'c': 30},
 {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3},
 {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}, {'a': 10, 'b': 20, 'c': 30}]
```

Comment: with `concat()` it works perfectly, thank you! Would it be better to use a different approach, or is flattening fine? If I remember the [dask-tutorial](https://github.com/dask/dask-tutorial) correctly, bags should be fine for ingesting/transforming, is this correct?

Comment: This seems like a reasonable approach to me.  You could also try [dask.delayed](http://dask.readthedocs.io/en/latest/delayed.html).  See notes on [working with collections](http://dask.readthedocs.io/en/latest/delayed-collections.html)

Comment: Just a heads up that .concat() didn't work for me but .flatten() did, in dask-2.14.0-py_0.
b = bag.from_sequence(files).map(read_file).flatten()